# Calling Oracle stored procedure output parameter with user defined value in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the oracle SP below and trying to call this SP in C# code behind but receiving an exception "wrong number or types of arguments in call" .How we can call this procedure in C# code. Please see the C# code below which I am currently using.

```
PROCEDURE UPDATE_KeyValue(
PAR_ID IN VARCHAR2,
PAR_STATUS OUT VARCHAR2 )
IS
BEGIN
--
PAR_STATUS := 'OK';
--
UPDATE TableName SET Key = 'Y'
 WHERE ID= PAR_ID 
--
COMMIT;
--
END UPDATE_KeyValue;
```

C# Code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE_KeyValue";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

OracleParameter PAR_ID1 = new OracleParameter();
PAR_ID1.ParameterName = "PAR_ID ";
PAR_ID1.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
PAR_ID1.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
PAR_ID1.Value = 131;
cmd.Parameters.Add(PAR_ID1);

OracleParameter PAR_STATUS1 = new OracleParameter();
PAR_STATUS1.ParameterName = "PAR_STATUS";
PAR_STATUS1.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
PAR_STATUS1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(PAR_STATUS1);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: what about the value for PAR_STATUS1 ?

Comment: Not sure if it matters or not, but why do you have a space at the end of the first parameter name?

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add(PAR_ID1);` should that be 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PAR_ID1", PAR_ID1);` assuming that's the parameter name

Comment: PAR_STATUS1 value already set as OK in SP.

Comment: you're also assigning an int to a varchar2 parameter in PAR_ID1

Comment: I changed the command object name to cmd1 as I used cmd for the previous comment also I added parameter size PAR_STATUS1.Size = 8000; for the output parameter and that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the command object name to cmd1 as I used cmd for the previous command also I added parameter size PAR_STATUS1.Size = 8000; for the output parameter and that solved my issue.